# Reference request: direct image of equivariant $\mathcal D$-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, d-modules

I'm hoping to find a detailed proof for the following well-known fact:

> Given respective algebraic group actions $G_1, G_2$ on smooth varieties $X_1, X_2$ over $\mathbb C$ with an algebraic group homomorphism $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ and a variety morphism $\psi: X_1 \to X_2$ that intertwines the group actions, the $\mathcal D$-module direct image $\psi_+$ sends $G_1$-equivariant quasi-coherent $\mathcal D_{X_1}$-modules to $G_2$-equivariant $\mathcal D_{X_2}$-modules.

In a draft version of *A Proof of Jantzen Conjectures* by Beilinson-Bernstein, it is claimed that the above result follows from smooth base change, but I'm failing to see how.

Thanks in advance!